# Laravel Eloquent Query Filter not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, filtering

Hi I am new to programming.
My Application have a filter function. where a user select two dates on front end. In eloquent query it should return records which are published by user itself or the record published by other user set to public and also filter records according to the dates given.
Here is code:

```
$maps = Mapdata::where('userid', Auth::user()->id)->ORwhere('public', 1)->whereBetween('from', array($request->from, $request->to))->ORwhereBetween('to', array($request->from, $request->to))->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

I have noticed that the date and time filter is not capturing all the relevant records. For example: a filter from 22/5/21 to 23/5/21 should return 3 records.[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Noo4u.png) but it showing [Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW66L.png). Also One of the records displayed is not even public record.
Please guide me how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap conditions in additional where to add `(` to query, so it should be probably something like this:

```
$maps = Mapdata::where(function($q) {
   $q->where('userid', Auth::user()->id)->orWhere('public', 1); 
})->where(function($q) use ($request) {
   $q->whereBetween('from', array($request->from, $request->to))->orWhereBetween('to', array($request->from, $request->to));
})->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Sir, That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to combine where between like below

```
$maps = Mapdata::where('userid', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->ORwhere('public', 1)->where(function($query){
                    $query->whereBetween('from', array($request->from, $request->to))
                    $query->ORwhereBetween('to', array($request->from, $request->to))
                    })->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Updated

```
$maps = Mapdata::where('userid', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->ORwhere('public', 1)->where(function($query)use($request){
                    $query->whereBetween('from', array($request->from, $request->to))
                    $query->ORwhereBetween('to', array($request->from, $request->to))
                    })->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. But now its showing Undefined variable '$request'  and also php strom indicating semicolon are missing please correct me 
"$maps = Mapdata::where('userid', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->ORwhere('public', 1)->where(function($query){
                    $query->whereBetween('from', array($request->from, $request->to));
                    $query->ORwhereBetween('to', array($request->from, $request->to));
                    })->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();"